# using IntentService for MediaPlayer playback

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-mediaplayer

Is it reasonable to use an `IntentService` for background `MediaPlayer` playback on demand? According to the [developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) an `IntentService` lasts only as long as it is doing actually work. Considering the resulting overhead of reinitializing the `MediaPlayer` everytime when I want to play a track again, it seems to be a bad Idea...

So my question is: How big is the actual resulting overhead using this kind of `Service`. Would it have a perceptable impact on the system's/application's performance? Should I use my own implementation of `Service` with a dedicated worker thread instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it reasonable to use an IntentService for background MediaPlayer playback on demand?

IMHO, no, because you can't really change tracks this way. Moreover, you need to know when the track completes, and you can't do that this way, except by leaking memory. Finally, it means that Android will terminate your process, possibly milliseconds after `onHandleIntent()` ends, which makes for a useless music player.

> Should I use my own implementation of Service with a dedicated worker thread instead?

You may not need a thread, as much of `MediaPlayer` is already asynchronous. Only if you would be doing network I/O or disk I/O or something on your own might you want your own thread. But having a `Service` -- and probably a foreground `Service` -- is the typical approach for a music player.

Comment: According to this : [article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) `start()` is not asynchronous. Wouldn't this block the caller's thread?

Comment: @CommonsWare what if my service is playing one in the meantime service get called, again and again, means sometimes I need to play one and sometimes multiple audio one by one then what do you suggest?
I don't need controls over media player means i don't need to pause or seek.
Which can handle onHandleIntent.
But in service i need to handle those intents manually with in onStartCommand.

Comment: @JahangirKabir: "what do you suggest?" -- a service can handle what you describe without much problem. "But in service i need to handle those intents manually with in onStartCommand" -- correct.